# How can I use Bing or Google Maps to show the traveled path?

Tags: google-maps, gis, bing-maps

I wonder if there's a functionality in Bing Maps or Google Maps that can present information of how I traveled on my bike. The input can be simply made by clicking on checkpoints and building the way manually or (even better), by some kind of integration with my phone.

No extreme exactness is required, just a simple checkpoints.

Comment: @DavidPostill Exactly. I intend to show that on my computer. The phone is only a collector of the information. In fact, I can even be open to manually click-in the points after I've got back home. If you disregard the part with the phone, do you still find the question off-topic? If so, would you mind recommending a better site? (It won't do with the Andorid related one, in such case.) I also edited the question to make it more on-topic.

Comment: If you use Googles [My Tracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks&hl=en) application to record the tracks on your phone you can open the exported `kml` file in Google Earth on your computer.  It's not quite Google Maps, but kinda close...

Comment: @Mokubai Didn't know about My Tracks application. And Google Earth **is** Google Maps, isn't it? Or maybe I'm confusing something. In Google Maps, I have this icon and when I click on it I can see the aerial view of fly imaginery. That's Google Earth, isn't it? Also, you might post your comment as a reply so it can get voted on.

Comment: That is essentially what Google earth is, but its a standalone application. Anything you can see in Maps you can see in Earth, but is more of a map browser than anything.  It's quite good for browsing recorded tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/android)?

> Track your runs, walks, **bike rides**, training workouts and all of the other fitness activities using the GPS in your Android Phone.

- Runkeeper data can be exported as GPX (GPS exchange) data (see [How to Export your RunKeeper data](https://support.runkeeper.com/hc/en-us/articles/201109886-How-to-Export-your-RunKeeper-data))
- GPX data can be imported into Google Maps (see [How to import gpx into Google Maps to make a GPS track viewer](http://www.urbanhikr.com/how-to-import-gpx-into-google-maps/))

  - You need to convert GPX to KML using [GPX2KML Converter](http://gpx2kml.com/).

Source [RunKeeper - GPS Track Run Walk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro&hl=en)

Comment: Or he could just go “the Google way” and use My Tracks. Though it supposedly sucks now.

Comment: I'm using Endomondo now but I used RunKeeper before so I'm fairly familiar with it. My preference would be not to need to convert as @DanielB mentions but, since he's warning that it sucks, I might go with your suggestion. At any rate - I have *KML* and *GPX* as googleables now (wasn't aware of these formats before) so I should be able to resolve the rest myself. +1 for the links. I'm guessing something like that applies to Endomondo as well.

Comment: If you ever need to convert *anything* GPS, I recommend [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/). Most programs that track can export GPX, because it’s widely supported.

Comment: @DanielB Would you mind posting your comment as a reply? It deserves voting. Also, you'll have the opportunity to elaborate on it supposedly being sucky. The same goes for the link to GpsBabel. Good stuff, mate. Get upvoted for it!

Comment: @KonradViltersten It sounds an interesting little project would be to work out how to automate as much as possible of the whole process  - otherwise you will have a lot of manual work to do every time you finish a bike ride ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed. However, in my case, I'll just need to prepare a few routes and that's it. I'll be posting the same trip over and over again for every new member of the group. So manual handling will do for now.